# I can't seem to get the pid of mousepad

Tags: linux, shell

What everyone recommends doesn't seem to work for mousepad:

```
#!/bin/bash
mousepad /etc/iptables/rules
pid=$!
echo "$pid"
while kill -0 "$pid"; do
  sleep 0.5
done
iptables-restore < /etc/iptables/rules
```

output:

````
*path removed*: line 5: kill: `': not a pid or valid job spec```
````

Is it possible to get it's pid (specific to this script)??

If you're not aware of what mousepad is (search engines certainly don't seem to know),
it's a simple, highly functional, lightweight, and extendable text editor similar to leafpad.

EDIT: apparently this actually did work, but for some reason, the newly spawned `mousepad` was assuming the pid of a window I'd had open for weeks.
(yes that means exactly what it sounds like, 2 separate process windows with the same pid)

Comment: `pgrep -f mousepad`  ?

Comment: that returns the pids of every open window I have, I'm looking for the specific pid for the script.

Comment: Try with `mousepad /etc/iptables/rules &`

Comment: huh, that works... I was thrown off because earlier I tried `... && iptables-restore /etc/iptables/rules` which opened extra tabs `/etc/iptables/rules | iptables-restore | && | rules`... thanks, I'll post an answer with the updated script.

Comment: @nullPointer nvm, while that works, the pid changes once the window displays: `line 5: kill: (16341) - No such process`

Comment: Normally this is displayed as soon as the process / pid is not there anymore (eg your text editor window closed?) - it is how your while loop exits

Comment: I assume it's likely a child/forked process as it displays when the window opens, the window itself has a different pid, which you can find with system monitor.

Comment: something I could probably do to isolate that is pgrep before and after to subtract the old array from the new to get the new pid, but that might be more than I need... is there something better??

Comment: then I think you should try obtaining the actual window pid (eg based on the parent pid, eg `pgrep -P $parent_pid`), and run your while loop on it instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments, try as below :

```
#!/bin/bash
mousepad /etc/iptables/rules &
pid=$$
child=$(pgrep -P $pid)
echo "$pid" 
echo "Child :" $child
while kill -0 $child; do
  sleep 0.5
done
iptables-restore < /etc/iptables/rules
```

Comment: unfortunately `child` is blank like my initial issue, if you want to test this, you can just `$ sudo iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules` (you may need to `$ sudo mkdir /etc/iptables` if you haven't already)

Comment: ok, I have no idea how to explain what happened, but for whatever reason, the spawned mousepad was assuming the id of a window that'd been running for weeks... once I closed that (and set `pid=$$` (done prior)), everything started working appropriately...

Comment: just to notify, even my initial script now works... I'm P'd

Comment: Sorry bout a necropost, but I figured out what was causing our issues. The **ONLY** time a new pid is created for `mousepad` is if the program is **initially** spawned by another user, meaning 5 windows opened by `root` all have the same pid for `root`. Not sure if you wanna update your answer for others who might need the exception.

Comment: @nullPointer Could you edit your answer and add an explanation what was the issue and how it has been fixed, please? Code-only answers are considered low quality.